Quip export full size image via api
I have a bunch of Quip spreadsheets with images in cells in column A. I'd like to download those images in full size.
When I run the below code I get thumbnail sized images. How can I get full sized images?
import fs from "fs/promises";

const baseUrl = "https://platform.quip.com";

const quipId = "REACTED"; // Quip document id
const quipApiToken = "REACTED"; // Quip API token

const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/2/threads/${quipId}/html`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${quipApiToken}`,
  },
});
const content = await res.json();
// console.log(content.html);

const regex = new RegExp(
  `src=["']/blob/(?<threadId>[\\w-]+)/(?<blobId>[\\w-]+)["']`,
  "gi"
);

let matches;
let output: { threadId: string; blobId: string }[] = [];
while ((matches = regex.exec(content.html))) {
  output.push(matches.groups);
}
// console.log(output);

for (const match of output) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `${baseUrl}/1/blob/${match.threadId}/${match.blobId}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${quipApiToken}`,
      },
    }
  );
  const blob = await res.blob();
  const buffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  await fs.writeFile(`blob-${match.blobId}.png`, Buffer.from(buffer));
  break;
}

